# Must one have a different suits for Yom Tov and Shabbos?

Tags: halacha, minhag, shabbat, clothing, yom-tov

I was wondering if it was preferable to have one suit for both Shabbos and Yom Tov or to have two different suits. And can you wear Shabbos/Yom Tov suits to other occasions like Bar Mitzvahs and weddings? And if minhag is applicable in this situation I would like the general Ashkenaz opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [S"A 529/1](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x2889) writes that one should have better clothing for Yom Tov than Shabbos.

> ובגדי יו"ט יהיו יותר טובים משל שבת

The Mishneh Berurah 529/12 writes that this obligation is only if one can afford it.

> בגדי יו"ט וכו' - משום דחייב בשמחה, וזהו ג"כ בכלל שמחה. ופשוט דכל זה
>   ג"כ בידו משגת:

I personally do not know many people that have special Yom Tov clothing.

Comment: <<You wrote; I personally do not know many people that have special Yom Tov clothing.>> In many Lithuanian communities in Eretz Yisrael it is customary, that married men wear a "(rabbinical) "frock" on Yom Tov, even those who don't wear it on a regular shabbos, or weekday.

Comment: Say there is a situation were you did not have Shabbos clothes before and there was a sale for suits, buy one get one free. Are you then obligated to have one suit for shabbos and one for yom tov?

Comment: @Yaakov - I"m assuming that your other choice would be to use them both equally for Shabbos and YomTov. Why shouldn't he designate one for Shabbos, and the other  for Yom Tov? Is it because the Shabbos suit won't last as long if he only uses one suit every Shabbos? Then I would think were back to the question of affordability.